# How is my boundaries outside of the array?

Tags: c#, arrays

On my array, on line 40, my boundaries are outside of the array, but I am not sure how to format this since this is my first program with a multi dimensional array. Please help me. Thanks! (Line 40 is `array[i, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100);`)

```
namespace Exercise6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            OtherClass aTable = new OtherClass(); //instantiate class

            Console.WriteLine("How many rows do you want your two-dimensional array to be?");
            aTable.SRows = Console.ReadLine(); //reads input for how many rows that the user would like
            aTable.IntRows = int.Parse(aTable.SRows); //convert rows to int

            Console.WriteLine("Thanks you! How many columns would you like your two-dimensional arry to be?");
            aTable.SColumns = Console.ReadLine(); //reads input for how many columns that the user would like
            aTable.IntColumns = int.Parse(aTable.SColumns); //convert columns to int

            //set two dimensional array based upon the size that the user has requested

            int[ , ] array = new int[aTable.IntColumns, aTable.IntRows];

            Random randomArray = new Random(); //call to random class to ask for random numbers

            for (int i = 0; i <= aTable.IntColumns; i++) // rows
            {
                array[i, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100); // for every value in each row, insert a random number
            }
            //both arrays here are overloaded. See this site to see if can get help. Site is below after last close loop
            for (int y = 0; y <= aTable.IntRows; y++) // columns
            {
                array[y, y] = randomArray.Next(0, 100);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(array);


        }
    }
}

namespace Exercise6
{
    class OtherClass
    {
        private string sRows;

        public string SRows { get; set; }

        private int intRows;

        public int IntRows { get; set; }

        private string sColumns;

        public string SColumns { get; set; }

        private int intColumns;

        public int IntColumns { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is because of your <= statement in the second argument of the For loop - as arrays use a zero-index, the last position is one less than the number of items in the array.

Comment: An array of size `s` has valid indices `i` where `0 <= i < s`, not `0 <= i <= s`. You're going one too far.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Now, just one thing. I fixed both of those loops... however, now when I try to run it, it displays my array as:

"System.Int32[,]"

Why did it not add anything to the array?

Comment: @me123 - Please create a new question regarding your array.

Comment: Here's how I fixed it: for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntRows; i++) //rows { for (int y = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; y++) //columns { array[i, y] = randomArray.Next(0,100); //for every value in the grid, place a random number up to #100 } //ends "sub for loop" } //ends first for loop Which, looks like I am getting closer. Thanks! But, now it still says that it is outside of the boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Change loop condition to `i < aTable.IntColumns`

You loop starts from 0 and goes to value of `aTable.IntColumns - 1`

and code becomes

```
for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; i++)
{
    array[i, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays are zero based, you can't go up to the max value:

```
// This line is incorrect
for (int i = 0; i <= aTable.IntColumns; i++)
```

That line should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; i++)
```

That will let it go from `0` to `aTable.IntColumns-1`, which are the valid indices for for an array of `aTable.IntColumns` length.  The same is true of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

C# arrays used zero-relative *offsets* as their indices. That means that for an array of length *n*, the *domain* of its index *i* is `0 <= i <= n-1`. A 100-element array has an index that ranges from 0-99. If you are trying to fill an m*n array with random values.

If your assignment is *fill* the array with random values (as seems likely), you'll need to do something like this:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i < aTable.IntRows ; i++ ) // rows
{
  for ( int j= 0 ; i < aTable.IntColumns ; j++ )
  {
    array[i,j] = randomArray.Next(0,100); // for every value in each row, insert a random number
  }
}
```

You might also note that your comments don't match your code: you are iterating over rows and checking the column limit and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aTable.IntColumns; i++) // rows
{
    array[i, 0] = randomArray.Next(0, 100); // for every value in each row, insert a random number
}
```

`i < aTable.IntColumns` should be the stopping criteria